# Why is the Ocean filler feature on Cartopy not working for my map?

Tags: python, cartopy

I am trying to make a plot of Europe with Cartopy and I want to fill in the ocean a different colour to the land. I believe I should be able to sue the line of code:
`ax.add_feature(ctp.feature.OCEAN, facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))`
in order to do this, however when I do the map shown below is produced. This is clearly not what I would like to achieve. Is anyone able to help me and see what is wrong with my code?

I have put the code in below for it to be reproduced locally.

```
import cartopy as ctp
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.EuroPP())
ax.add_feature(ctp.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(ctp.feature.OCEAN,facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection `ccrs.EuroPP()` [source](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/_modules/cartopy/crs.html#EuroPP)  is a subclass of UTM, which is a subclass of `transversemercator`. The complexities of subclassing may be the cause of the bad result. You can try my code that uses straight forward projection `TransverseMercator(central_longitude=10)` which should be nearly equivalent with `EuroPP`. The values in `ax.set_extent()` can be adjusted to get the areas you want on the map.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

# Start- relevant code
pp_euro = ccrs.TransverseMercator(central_longitude=10)
ax = plt.axes(projection=pp_euro)
ax.set_extent([-1800000, 2050000, 4000000, 8000000], crs=pp_euro)
# End- relevant code

ax.add_feature(ctp.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(ctp.feature.OCEAN,facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: europp]

Comment: Thank you very much - this has worked well!

Comment: @USer555 The correct way to thank is accepting my answer, by clicking the button. ;p